# Scaling websocket client connections (not server) to multiple servers

Tags: architecture, scalability, distributed-computing, websockets

I wrote a Slack bot which must connect to Slack teams through websocket connections. Since the bot might be used by thousands of team, I will eventually need to distribute the teams across multiple servers. New teams are added through an HTTP server which handles the initial OAuth authentication.

I'm looking for a solutions that will help me achieve the following:

- When a server goes down or reboots, all the teams it was assigned to must be re-assigned to the remaining servers. It's ok if the connection to the Slack team temporarily goes down as long as the team is quickly picked up by a server.
- When a team is added, it gets assigned to the less "busy" server. Busy could be simply defined by the amount of team it currently handles.
- I'd like to do all of this with minimal custom code to write.

So far, I've considered the following solutions:

1) [Work queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) with RabbitMQ. Bot servers compete to receive teams. That's an OK solution though I need a reliable way to put back teams in the queue when a server goes down.

2) Write a custom "orchestration" service. The orchestration service would receive teams from the http server and dispatch them to a cluster of servers. It would need to keep track of when servers go down and which teams need to be re-assigned. I'm not really sure how to write such a service reliably and this would become a single point of failure.

3) Your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you're looking for advice on how to achieve load balancing.  Even with the limitations you've offered, this is a pretty broad topic.

One possible solution:

Starting under the assumption that you have some means for any arbitrary client to obtain a list of currently active servers, you could use some variation on [Consistent Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) or [Rendezvous Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_hashing).

As a simplified example, you map each server to numerous random bucket values between 0 and 1.  For a given client, you hash some sort of client id (e.g., the client's IP address) to a number, then send it to the server with a bucket which is closest to the selected server<sup>[1]</sup>.

There are several benefits to this approach:

- Other than maintaining the list of servers, all of this logic can be
  done client-side.
- The logic is incredibly simple; implementing this
  functionality should only require 10-20 lines of code.
- Adding or
  removing servers is handled cleanly.  When a server is added, most clients will not switch servers.  When a server is lost, only that server's clients will be remapped.

The downside of this approach is that it is random.  There is a risk that load will not be distributed evenly, especially if the number of clients is low.

<sub>[1] This calculation wraps (hence why most discussions talk about angles or circles), but the impact of ignoring this is pretty small.  The simplest fix is to add an extra `1+Min(bucket_value)` bucket.  Basically, 0.01 should be treated as closer to 0.99 than to 0.5 to avoid weighing the highest and lowest bucket values less unevenly.</sub>